# how to fix 'spark_dependencies function not found within extension package mleap' error in r

Tags: sparklyr

how to fix 'spark_dependencies function not found within extension package mleap' error in Rstudio, notice that i have failed previously to  install mleap package. thanks

Comment: Ehh, don't you think that if some package is missing, it's functions would not be available?

Comment: If it is, the missing package should be mentioned in the error message..